# Bottom to top, right to left position small rectangles inside a bigger one (calendar)

Tags: html, css

I'm building a calendar, and this is what I'm after:
http://postimg.org/image/vpd10bkqt/

So basically I want to show all the events as a small rectangle inside the
appropriate day's big rectangle.

The difficulty is the first element should be shown at the bottom right corner,
and should be filling form right to left and bottom to top.

I think the simplest solution would be if a rectangle would be a
span element with a solid border around it, and it contains a dot as text.

Here is a jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/jv392gmv/

CSS:

```
    section#calendar {
        width: 970px;
    }

    time {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin: 4px;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: x-large;
        font-weight: 900;
        border: 1px solid #c3c7c7;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    time.notmonth {
        background: #777;
    }
    section#calendar h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    section#calendar time a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
        padding: 3px 3px 0 0;
        color: #f55b2c;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    section#calendar time a:hover {
        color: #000;
        }

    span.event {
      top: 10%;
      left: 7px;
      position: relative;
        border-color: #222;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-width: 5px;

    }
```

HTML:

```
    <section id="calendar">
      <h1>
      <a href="prevyear" title="previous" accesskey=",">←</a>
      July 2015
      <a href="/nextyear" title="next" accesskey=".">→</a>
      </h1>
      <time datetime="2011-05-29">
        <a href="#">29</a>
         <!-- <span class="event">.</span> -->
      </time>
    </section>
```

Anyone has any idea how to achieve it?

The original time tag idea came from here:
http://thenewcode.com/355/HTML5-Calendar-With-CSS3-and-Microdata

Comment: I guess you only achieve this with a piece of javascript to reorder lines. Right to left is easy with `float:right` in the elements, but bottom to top is more complicated. You must to put float:right and then with javascript reorder lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the container, set a rotation of 180 deg.

In the children, rotate again to get them upright

```css
.base {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.children {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div >123</div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="children">1</div>
    <div class="children">2</div>
    <div class="children">3</div>
    <div class="children">4</div>
    <div class="children">5</div>
    <div class="children">6</div>
    <div class="children">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not make it work, because the date is also rotated. Please have a look at the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jv392gmv/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jv392gmv/5/ I think we ironed out all the remaining quirks. Feel free to point out some obvious mistakes!:) I'm going to accept your answer this evening.